# fetch api keep saving only the first input value in django with dynamic formset, never mind fixed it :)

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api, formset

answer:solution↓    --->changes in views.py

return JsonResponse() should be written at first for loop, because second for loop keep returning the JsonResponse every time when looping the second loop.i hope you understand.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(len(formset)):
            fields = request.POST.get(f'items-{str(i)}-fields')
            title_id = request.POST.get('title')
            print(title_id)
            print(fields)
            for j in Create_topic.objects.all():
                if j.title == title_id:
                    Topic_field(choose_topic = j,field = fields).save()
                    print('saved')
                    data_fields = {'status':'success'}
            return JsonResponse({'status':'success'},safe=False)
```

but without using fetch api, the django save all of my input values but it keep refreshing. I need to use fetch api.
please guide me through this, i am beginner!

html

```
<div>
            <form method="post" id="save_multiple_fields">
                <h4>Choose the topic and write additional informations</h4>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="id_title"></label>
                <select name="title" id="id_title" class="form-control">
                    <option value selected>------</option>
                    <!-- {% for i in create_topic_models %}
                        <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i}}</option>
                    {% endfor %} -->
                </select>
                 {{ select_title_form }}
                <br>
                <div class="form_list">
                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                    {% for formset_form in formset %}
                        <div class="real_form">
                            {{ formset_form.as_p }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="empty_form">{{ formset.empty_form.as_p }}</div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_fields">add title box with textarea</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" id="save_fields">
            </form>
            <div id="fields_list">
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript to add input fields

```
const form_count = document.getElementsByClassName('real_form');
    const id_items_TOTAL_FORMS = document.getElementById('id_items-TOTAL_FORMS')

    var add_fields = document.getElementById('add_fields');
    add_fields.addEventListener('click',add_fields_function);
    function add_fields_function(event){
        if(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        // console.log(form_count.length)

        const empty_form = document.querySelector('.empty_form').cloneNode(true);
        const form_list = document.querySelector('.form_list');
        empty_form.setAttribute('class','real_form');
        empty_form.setAttribute('id',`form-${form_count.length}`)

        id_items_TOTAL_FORMS.setAttribute('value',form_count.length + 1);

        const regex = new RegExp('__prefix__','g');
        empty_form.innerHTML = empty_form.innerHTML.replace(regex,form_count.length);

        form_list.append(empty_form);

    }
```

javascript with fetch api
and ignore the comments

```
// saving multiple inputs fields
    document.getElementById('save_multiple_fields').addEventListener('submit',save_multiple_inputs);
    function save_multiple_inputs(e){
        if(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        const formData = new FormData(this);

        console.log(`---------${formData}`)

        fetch('{% url "jobs:createjob" %}',{
            method:'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(status => {
            console.log('success',status);
            alert('saved');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('error,',error);
        })
    }
```

views.py

and ignore the comments

```
def createjob(request):
    form = CreateJobForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    create_topic_form = Create_topic_Form(request.POST or None)
    formset = formset_fac(request.POST or None,prefix = 'items')

    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #   print(request.POST.get(f'items-{str(0)}-fields'))

    createjob_model = CreateJob.objects.all()
    # create_topic_models = Create_topic.objects.filter(createjob = max([i.id for i in CreateJob.objects.all()]))

    # if form.is_valid():
    #   obj = form.save(commit = False)
    #   obj.user = request.user
    #   obj.save()
    #   print(obj.id)
    #   # data = {'name':form.cleaned_data['company_name']}
    #   data = {'id':obj.id}
    #   # return redirect('jobs:home')
    #   messages.add_message(request,messages.SUCCESS,'Job Created!')
    #   return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(len(formset)):
            fields = request.POST.get(f'items-{str(i)}-fields')
            title_id = request.POST.get('title')
            print(title_id)
            print(fields)
            for j in Create_topic.objects.all():
                if j.title == title_id:
                    Topic_field(choose_topic = j,field = fields).save()
                    print('saved')
                    data_fields = {'status':'success'}
                    return JsonResponse(data_fields,safe=False)
        


    context = {
        'form':form,
        'formset':formset,
        'create_topic_form':create_topic_form,
        # 'create_topic_models':create_topic_models,
        'createjob_model':createjob_model,
        }
    return render(request,'cj_form.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class TimeStampModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-modified_at','-created_at']
        abstract = True

class CreateJob(TimeStampModel):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts',blank=True,null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    company_description = models.TextField()
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)

    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.company_name)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        # About_more_job_info.objects.create(createjob = self)

class Create_topic(models.Model):
    createjob = models.ForeignKey(CreateJob,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class Topic_field(models.Model):
    choose_topic = models.ForeignKey(Create_topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.choose_topic}-{self.field}"
```

please guide me through this!